# Promote nested array of struct by multi level for XML decoding

Tags: xml, go, struct

I have a struct with nested array of struct in format below, I have promoted News struct which is in struct array **URL**

**My RSS Feed is** : https://foreignpolicy.com/feed/

Here is the tool I used to **generate Go struct from my RSS feed** [XML to Go struct](https://www.onlinetool.io/xmltogo/)

```
type Rss struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rss"`
    Channel struct {
        URL []struct {
            News
        } `xml:"item"`
    } `xml:"channel"`
}
type News struct {
    Loc         string `xml:"link"`
    Publishdate string `xml:"pubDate"`
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Summary     string `xml:"description"`
}
```

Here is the [Goplayround promote News struct](https://go.dev/play/p/fKzMG0wxo81)

I want to go one step further to promote everything in Channel , so that I can access items in **News** struct directly from top most **Rss** struct:

```
type Rss struct {
    XMLName xml.Name `xml:"rss"`
    Channel --> seem NOT working ?
}
type Channel struct {
    URL []struct {
        News
    }
}
type News struct {
    Loc         string `xml:"channel>item>link"` ---> is it the right xml tag ?
    Publishdate string `xml:"pubDate"` ---> or this is the right xml tag ?
    Title       string `xml:"title"`
    Summary     string `xml:"description"`
}
```

So I can print it as below :

```
var URLset Rss
if xmlBytes, err := getXML(url); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("Failed to get XML: %v", err)
} else {
    xml.Unmarshal(xmlBytes, &URLset)
}
/************************** XML parser *************************/
for _, URLElement := range **URLset.URL** {
    fmt.Println("URLElement:", URLElement)
    fmt.Println(
        "[Element]:",
        "\nTitle #", URLElement.Title,
        "\nPublicationDate #", URLElement.Publishdate,
        "\nSummary#", URLElement.Summary,
        "\nLoc #", URLElement.Loc,
        "\n")
}
```

But it seems print nothing
[Goplayground Promote Channel](https://go.dev/play/p/Zertl9-UZ0c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```golang
URL []struct { News } `xml:"channel>item"`
```

and remove the `channel>item` from the `Loc`'s tag.

---

The embedding of the `News` type in `[]struct{ }` seems superfluous. So you can instead do

```golang
URL []News `xml:"channel>item"`
```

and you'll get the same result.

---

And I'd recommend that you use names that match the XML's element names, i.e. `Item` instead of `News` and `Items` instead of `URL`.

```golang
Items []Item `xml:"channel>item"`
```

https://go.dev/play/p/1Ig7wtxckqJ

---

The `xml.Unmarshal` documentation on `>` in struct tags says the following:

> If the XML element contains a sub-element whose name matches the
> prefix of a tag formatted as "a" or "a>b>c", unmarshal will descend
> into the XML structure looking for elements with the given names, and
> will map the innermost elements to that struct field. A tag starting
> with ">" is equivalent to one starting with the field name followed by
> ">".

https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/xml@go1.18.2#Unmarshal

Comment: one more question `xml:"channel>item"` it is used as a xml tag , so that when parse XML the parser can tell which xml tag to follow ?

Comment: @Jia I've updated the answer by adding the relevant documentation.